# Get list of unique codes that are consecutive with up to and including a 6 day buffer

Tags: sql, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

**Problem**

What are the start and end dates of a code running?

I know this is similar to other Gaps and Islands problems already on here but I have not found a question that is complicated by the followingtwo issues:

- A code can start and end more than once
- A code can run with up to and including 6 days of gaps (This will be explained further below)

**Data**

This is the T-SQL data that I have:

```
Table

Code        | Date          
--------------------------------
1000        | 01-31-2015    
1000        | 02-01-2015    
1000        | 02-02-2015    
1000        | 02-03-2015    
1000        | 02-09-2015    
1000        | 02-10-2015    
1000        | 02-17-2015    
1001        | 02-01-2015    
1001        | 02-02-2015    
1001        | 02-04-2015    
1001        | 02-05-2015    
1001        | 02-12-2015    
1001        | 02-19-2015
```

**Ideal Solution**

What I want to my sql query to return is:

```
Code        | StartDate     | EndDate       | Run
--------------------------------------------------------
1000        | 01-31-2015    | 02-10-2015    | 1 
1000        | 02-17-2015    | 02-17-2015    | 2
1001        | 02-01-2015    | 02-05-2015    | 3
1001        | 02-12-2015    | 02-12-2015    | 4
1001        | 02-19-2015    | 02-19-2015    | 5
```

To explain further, lets take an example:

Code 1000 runs in consecutive days from 01-31-2015 to 02-03-2015. There is then a 6 day gap until it running from 02-09-2015 to 02-10-2015. As a 6 day gap is acceptable, the start date for that run is defined as 01-31-2015 and the end date as 02-03-2015.

However, in contrast, Code 1001 runs on 02-12-2015 and 02-19-2015. As there is a 7 day gap between these, they are not considered to be in the same run.

All help is greatly appreciated so thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify where groups start.  In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()` for this purpose.  Then, by accumulating the number of starts before a given row, you have a group.  And, with a group, you can aggregation.

This looks like:

```
select code, min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate,
       row_number() over (partition by code order by min(date)) as run
from (select t.*,
             sum(IsGroupStart) over (partition by code order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when dateadd(day, -6, date) >
                              lag(date) over (partition by code order by date)
                         then 1 else 0
                     end) as IsGroupStart
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, code;
```

Comment: I edited the code in line 2 to: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mediaCode) as run to get a unique identifier for each row but otherwise that was perfect! Thank you @Gordon!